# Split into mutiple columns by a certain format

Tags: r

I would like to split a certain format of data from one column into multiple columns. Below are my sample data :

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1,2),data=c('^apple:1%2%3^orange:3%4%5',
                                   '^apple:4%5%6^orange:7%8%9'))
#    id    data
#    1    ^apple:1%2%3^orange:3%4%5
#    2    ^apple:4%5%6^orange:7%8%9
```

which will then gives the following output

```
 id   data_apple_A  data_apple_B  data_apple_C  data_orange_A  data_orange_B  data_orange_C
 1       1               2              3             3             4              5
 2       4               5              6             7             8              9
```

I am using the following code to try and get the values for A,B and C(they could be decimal values):

```
cSplit(df, "data", sep="\\^", fixed = FALSE,direction= "long")[, c('valA','valB','valC')
        :=(str_extract(data, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")),str_extract(data, "(?<=%)\\d+\\.*\\d*"),
        str_extract(data, "(?<=%)\\d+\\.*\\d*$") ][]
```

but was getting the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(cSplit(df, "data", sep = "\\^", fixed = FALSE,  : 
  Provide either 'by' or 'keyby' but not both
```

Do note that apple and orange is just a placeholder. it could be characters and the number of ^(str): could also be different for each row.
Also, A B C are fixed. for every ^(str): , there will only be 3 decimal or non decimal numbers in the format of 1%2%3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the library `tidyverse`. I don't know how to do exactly but take a look at this :http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `tidyr::extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  extract(data, 
          into = paste(rep("data", 6),
                       c("apple", "orange"),
                       rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2), sep = "_"), 
          regex = "\\^apple:([0-9])\\%([0-9])\\%([0-9])\\^orange:([0-9])\\%([0-9])\\%([0-9])")
```

Comment: As the answer is perfect I prefer a more comprehensive way like: `df %>% 
  mutate(data=gsub("\\^|:|apple","",data)) %>% 
  separate(data,into = c("apple", "orange"), sep="orange") %>% 
  separate(apple, into=paste("apple",LETTERS[1:3], sep="_"), sep="[%]") %>% 
  separate(orange, into=paste("orange",LETTERS[1:3], sep="_"), sep="[%]") `

Comment: I forgot to mention that Apple and orange are just placeholders to give an example. In actual case, they could be anything and i need to be able to accept anything. A B C are fixed though.